# "sh: #: unknown operand" - How do I get rid of this error on shell script?

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a shell script which when executed works fine, but gives a warning:

```
sh: #: unknown operand
```

In this shell script, I want to comment out the processes namely "process1" and "process2", which are also shell scripts designed for other tasks, and after commenting them out, I want to transfer the contents of path1 to a file in path2

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
rootpath="/opt/storage"
datestring=`date +"%y-%m-%d"`
touch newfile1
touch newfile2
autorun_contents=`cat FILE1`
if [ ! -f ${FILE1} ] || [ -z "`echo \"${FILE1}\" | tail -10 | grep EOF`" ]; then
echo "Something was wrong with the file"
return
fi
sed "s/.\/process1/# .\/process1/g" FILE1 > FILE2 | echo "Hi1"
sed "s/.\/process2/# .\/process2/g" FILE1 > FILE2 | echo "Hi2"
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try this `sed -i 's/.\/process1/\#.\/process1/g'`1